# Apache RewriteRule with multiple ampersands

Tags: mod-rewrite

What I need to get working:

Request:

`http://site.com/ipdb/remote&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsite.com%2F&shortname=X`

Rule:

`RewriteRule ^remote&url=(.+?)&shortname=(.+?)$ /ipdb/?request=remote-access&url=$1&shortname=$2 [L]`

The above rule is not working. Any solution?

What I've working:

Request: http://site.com/ipdb/dwnlds&dl=X

Rule:

`RewriteRule ^dwnlds&dl=(.+?)$ /ipdb/?request=downloads&download=$1`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `QSA` Flag

```
AllowEncodedSlashes On

RewriteRule ^ipdb/remote$ /ipdb/?request=remote-access [B,QSA,L]
```

Ok I think I get what you need now.
You should be able to completely hide the request=remote-access
Do something like.

```
RewriteRule access/(.*)/(.*) /ipdb/?request=remote-access&url=$1&shortname=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}$ [L]
```

Then you should be able to give the link as `http://localhost/access/mysite.com/ppl`

Comment: Thanks but the QSA and NE flags did not fixed the issue.

Comment: I got 404 error because rewrite was not working. I just managed to track down the issue to urlencoded characters. That causes the rule to not work. Any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: RewriteRule does not like urlencoded chars in url parameter: http%3A%2F%2Fsite.com%2F

Comment: Since the URL is already encoded, remove NE. Try just `[QSA, L]`

Comment: Removing the NE did not helped. If I don't urlencode the URL; I'll receive Access forbidden from Apache. I would like to show the URL to the user. One trick would be base64encode the URL but that's not what I want.

Comment: It looks like there are slashes because of the HTTP part. Use the B flag and try the AllowEncodedSlashes On parameter. The B flag unencodes it before encoding and forwarding it. Updated answer.

Comment: I meant the B flag prevents it from unescaping the encoded URL.

Comment: With the B flag and/or AllowEncodedSlashes On it will end up in permission denied (403).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32529/discussion-between-pjack-and-nix)